# Присвоение классов записям в цикле по заданному алгоритму

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Нужна помощь организовать вывод постов в WordPress, я голову сломал уже. Сетка Bootstrap. Первые 3 — это `.col-sm-4`, а остальные 2 записи — `.col-sm-6`. И повторить этот цикл.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, вашу попытку реализовать описанный функционал. Что именно у вас не получилось? Получить список записей? Разбить список на группы по три элемента? На каком этапе застопорились?

Comment: если у вас цикл, то вы ведь можете считать его итерации, проверить больше там 3х или нет?

Comment: Считайте количество выведённых постов, берите от него остаток от деления на 5. Если 0-2, то col-sm-4, если 3-4, то col-sm-6.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($i < 3) : ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
           ...
        <div>

    <?php elseif($i < 5) : ?>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
           ...
        <div>

    <?php else: 
        $i = -1; 
    endif; ?>

    <?php $i++; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```